# json tree file,url to csv file using python

Tags: json, python-2.7

I am trying to convert a number of .json files to .csv's using Python 2.7

Is there any general way to convert a json file to a csv?

PS: I saw various similar solutions on stackoverflow.com but they were very specific 
to json tree and doesn't work if the tree structure changes. I am new to this site and am sorry for my bad english and reposting ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic thing to understand is that json and csv files are extremely different on a very fundamental level.

A csv file is just a series of value separated by commas, this is useful for defining data like those in relational databases where you have exactly the same fields repeated for a large number of objects.

A json file has structure to it, there is no straightforward way to represent any kind of tree structure in a csv. You can have various types of foreign key relationships, but when it comes right down to it, trees don't make any sense in a csv file.

My advice to you would be to reconsider using a csv or post your specific example because for the vast majority of cases, there is no sensible way to convert a json document into a csv.